# How do i iterate through this JSON object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How do I pull out ColumnValues[i] using javascript from this JSON sample using two instances with keys = "1" and "2" as shown below.  This is just a sample my original JSON object has 500+ entries like this with key = "1", "2", "3", "4", etc.  When I retrieve the length of the object the value that is returned equals 1 so using for loop does not work with the length property.  Appreciate any help.

JSON object below

```
[
 {
    "1": {
        "ChildCount": 0,
        "ColumnIndentLevel": 0,
        "DescendantCount": 0,
        "IndentLevel": 0,
        "IsCategory": false,
        "IsConflict": false,
        "IsDocument": true,
        "IsTotal": false,
        "IsValid": true,
        "NoteID": "3962",
        "SiblingCount": 2,
        "UniversalID": "E8D5D7E88B08CBD686257CD6007470E5",
        "ColumnValues": {
            "0": "03297",
            "1": "Amelia Tang",
            "2": "NBK3456",
            "3": "FHA",
            "4": "2008/10/03 00:00:00 UTC-0000",
            "5": "Withdrawn by SASE Administration",
            "6": "Approver Level 2",
            "7": "Reinstatement"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "ChildCount": 0,
        "ColumnIndentLevel": 0,
        "DescendantCount": 0,
        "IndentLevel": 0,
        "IsCategory": false,
        "IsConflict": false,
        "IsDocument": true,
        "IsTotal": false,
        "IsValid": true,
        "NoteID": "7972",
        "SiblingCount": 2,
        "UniversalID": "4CEE012B8D60A86A86257CD6007657B0",
        "ColumnValues": {
            "0": "20004484",
            "1": "Anthony Susino",
            "2": "",
            "3": "Conventional",
            "4": "2009/05/11 00:00:00 UTC-0000",
            "5": "Withdrawn by SASE Administration",
            "6": "",
            "7": ""
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Where is the JSON generated from? If it is intended to be an array then it's wrong and should be corrected. Do you control the generation?

Comment: It's of the length `0` because the outer array has only a single item.

Comment: you need to learn bit of javascript on to know object vs arrays and iterating over object properties vs arrays. When you do length on a non array object, you have clearly misunderstood the concept.

Comment: I would suggest you to use this structure instead:
[
{"ChildCount": 0,...}, 
{"ChildCount": 0,...}, 
{"ChildCount": 0,....},....
]

Answer (score 1):

```
var ColumnValues = /* that object */,
    i = 0;         //this makes sure the object is iterated in an ascending order
while(i++ in ColumnValuesd){         //and ignores irrelevant properties that are
    var item = ColumnValues[i];      //inherited from Object's prototype.
    //do something
}
```

Same goes for the most-top level keys.

Comment: `i++ in ColumnValues` might be a bit more semantically expected. Btw, you're incrementing twice

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
for (var key in yourObject) { // key will be "1", "2", ...
    var value = yourObject[key];

    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robby.  Got me going in the right direction.  What actually worked for me was `var oJson = <object>;
for(var item in oJson[0])
{
alert(oJson[0][item]["ColumnValues"]["1"]);     
}`